# Undefined variable: data", exception: "ErrorException",…}

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have an alias in this code that is RIGHT (no_antrian, 3) as code

when I call the alias with $ code, laravel says Undefined variable: data ", exception:" ErrorException ", ...}

```
        $result = DB::table('data_antrian')->select(DB::raw('RIGHT(no_antrian,3) as kode'))->where('tanggal', '=', $tanggal)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)->get();


        $rows = DB::table('data_antrian')->where('tanggal', '=', $tanggal)->count();

        if ($rows > 0) {
            // $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            // $kode = $data['kode']+1;
            $kode = $data['kode']+1;
        } else {
            $kode = '001';
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have data defined, meanwhile also you treat your `$result` variable as a single entity and it is a collection. Therefor i think this is what you want to do.

```
$result = DB::table('data_antrian')->select(DB::raw('RIGHT(no_antrian,3) as kode'))->where('tanggal', '=', $tanggal)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)->first();
$rows = DB::table('data_antrian')->where('tanggal', '=', $tanggal)->count();

if ($rows > 0) {
    $kode = $result->kode + 1;
} else {
    $kode = '001';
}
```

In the first query instead of `get()`, i only get a single result which you can since you only `take(1)`. Using result instead of data and using it as an object since it is an object.

Comment: thank you, your suggestion was very helpful, make my code return to work properly.